# Sorting divs based on array order

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a drag and drop design that, when you rearrange the draggable items, pushes their ids to an array. So i’ll have an array like:

```
["#fake-block_1","#fake-block_3","#fake-block_2"]
```

Behind the scenes, I want to rearrange some corresponding divs that share the same numeric value as these blocks, e.g., `#fake-block_1` maps on to `#real-block_1`. I can’t quite seem to grasp how I would get this rearrangement to happen. Heres what I currently have:

```
$('.js-fake-block’).each(function(i){

  $this = $(this);
  $array = new Array();
  $delimiter = '_';

  $array.push($this.attr("id").split($delimiter)[1]);
  $array.forEach(function(item,index){
    $realBlockId = "#real-block_”+[item];
  });
});
```

So I loop through every “fake block”, split their ID by an underscore (I match fake and real with the same numeric value), add them into an array, and then have the real Ids made up again… but after that I’m lost. No idea how I’d sort the “real blocks” based on this "fake blocks" arrays order.

Comment: Write `'` instead of `’` and `"` instead of `”`.

Comment: not exactly helpful. thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of what you're trying to do  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/N_Ate/tcswnjx4/)

```
function sortDom(selectorArray) {
    while (selectorArray.length) {
        let $el = $(selectorArray.pop());
        $el.parent().prepend($el);
    }
}

//Usage//
$('.ordinal').on('click', function() {
    sortDom(['#_01', '#_02', '#_03', '#_04', '#_05', '#_06', '#_07', '#_08', '#_09', '#_10']);
});
$('.reversed').on('click', function() {
    sortDom(['#_10', '#_09', '#_08', '#_07', '#_06', '#_05', '#_04', '#_03', '#_02', '#_01']);
});
$('.jumbled').on('click', function() {
    sortDom(['#_07', '#_01', '#_10', '#_04', '#_02', '#_03', '#_06', '#_05', '#_09', '#_08']);
});
```

Note this method does not enforce the array elements reference dom elements attached to the same parent and it does not enforce that all child elements of the parent must be referenced in the array. Unreferenced child elements will be pushed to the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the `sort` method to describe how to the sort elements and then re-set the html of the parent:

```
var sortedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
    // If referring to your array of IDs, you can use indexOf($(a).attr("id"))
    return $(a).attr("id") > $(b).attr("id");
});

$("#container").html(sortedDivs);
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vuqebg1s/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need to save numbers in array and loop again to create a new array .. you can just use the next code

```
$array = [];  // use array outside the loop 
$('.js-fake-block').each(function(i){
  var $this = $(this);
  var $delimiter = '_';
  var SplitNum = $this.attr("id").split($delimiter);
  $array.push("#real-block_" + SplitNum[1]);
});
console.log($array);
```

**Working example**

```js
$array = [];  // use array outside the loop 
$('.js-fake-block').each(function(i){
  var $this = $(this);
  var $delimiter = '_';
  var SplitNum = $this.attr("id").split($delimiter);
  $array.push("#real-block_" + SplitNum[1]);
});
console.log($array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="js-fake-block" id="fake-block_1"></div>
<div class="js-fake-block" id="fake-block_3"></div>
<div class="js-fake-block" id="fake-block_5"></div>
<div class="js-fake-block" id="fake-block_4"></div>
<div class="js-fake-block" id="fake-block_2"></div>
```

Comment: sorry i might not have explained myself very well! I’m trying to take already existing html and rearrange it so it matches all those fake-block IDs. so the sorting of the real blocks should match how you have sorted the fake blocks. I’m struggling to understand how to do that.